# Tooltip does not wrap/ignores max width

Tags: java, width, tooltip, javafx, word-wrap

I am trying to add a tooltip to my `ToggleButton` to explain to the user what's going to happen if they press it. The problem is, my explanation is too long and the tooltip cuts it off with "..." (the ellipsis string, was it?) Anyway, when I set the max/pref width via a `TooltipBuilder` like in this example:

```
this.watched = new ToggleButton("Watched?");
Tooltip tooltip = TooltipBuilder.create().wrapText(true).text(
                "Rather than specifying individual images, you can make this source \'watched\',which means that every" + 
                " time this gallery is viewed, all the images in this directory will be listed.").build();
tooltip.prefWidth(50);
watched.setTooltip(tooltip);
```

I get this result:

[image: tooltip]

My attempts to set the width via `maxWidth(double)`, `maxWidthProperty().set(double)`, `prefWidth(double)`, and `prefWidthProperty().set(double)` have been ignored.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my code, I was setting `wrapText(boolean)` before setting the width. It seems like JavaFX doesn't like this so much. I changed it to look something like this:

```
TooltipBuilder.create().prefWidth(300).wrapText(true).<other properties>.build();
```

This gives me a successful wrap!

[image]

Comment: Note that `TooltipBuilder` is deprecated in Java v8 update 101 (it still works though).

Answer (score 0):

In javaFx 2.2 use this:

```
Tooltip toolTip = TooltipBuilder.create().text(string).prefWidth(500).wrapText(true).build();
```